# Photoshop: can't make red rectangle but RGB channel is on

Tags: adobe-photoshop, rgb

Accidentally pressed something like ⌘ 5, and it must have changed the color channels. I made sure they are visible now, but the red is acting up. If I make the rectangle bright red it works, but a shade darker/lighter and the rectangle turns grey. Similarly, the red in my image is gone as if has just outlined things in red (should have red background with white text). What should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The shape you have shown is not matching with your RGB chanel image. Any how check your layer mode, it seems to me that your layer mode is some thing other than normal like Luminosity

Comment: for brevity I just made a rectangle, my real problem is  all the red in the channel image is gone. also where do I find layer mode? going to `image > mode` on i'm `RGB 16 bit/channel`

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason for this behavior to affect multiple layers and be sensitive both to increases and decreases in the red color. I tried several different ideas but was not able to reproduce this, so I'm thinking Photoshop just got confused somewhere along the line.

The first thing, then, would be to Save As, then quit Photoshop completely. Reopen the document in a fresh instance of Photoshop and see if the problem is still there.

If the problem is persisting, restart your OS.

If that doesn't clear it, again quit Photoshop and this time, when you reopen the program hold down Ctl, Alt and Shift (Cmd, Option and Shift) while it is loading. Answer "yes" to the question about deleting preferences. Now reopen the document.

If that *still* hasn't got rid of the problem, expand the question with screenshots of your Layers panel showing all the layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the bit depth too low, you'll only be able to produce a couple of reds. Your red channel is probably not RGB 16 in that layer.